# How to read a partitioned parquet directory with CTAS in Athena?

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena, create-table, ctas

Given an S3 directory stored in partitioned parquet in `s3://path_to_my_data/abc_dataset/`  as such:

```
s3://path_to_my_data/abc_dataset/
  source_lang=en_US/
  source_lang=en_GB/
  source_lang=zh_CN/
  source_lang=zh_TW/
```

When I've tried to read the dataset without partition, CTAS creates the table as expected I can I read with `select * from abc`:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc (
  key_id STRING,
  value_text STRING,
  price INT
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://path_to_my_data/abc_dataset/source_lang=en_US/'
tblproperties ("parquet.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

But when I tried to read the parent directory with partition, empty tables were created and `select * from abc` returns no records:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc (
  key_id STRING,
  value_text STRING,
  price INT
)
PARTITIONED BY (source_locale STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://path_to_my_data/abc_dataset/'
tblproperties ("parquet.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

**How to read a partitioned parquet directory with CTAS in Athena?**

Answer (score 1):

You can also follow this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc (
  key_id STRING,
  value_text STRING,
  price INT
)
PARTITIONED BY (source_locale STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://path_to_my_data/abc_dataset/'
tblproperties ("parquet.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

after creating the table run this query in Athena

```
msck repair table TABLENAME
```

The `msck repair table TABLENAME` will automatically load all the partition in Glue DataCatalog. After that you can start using partition.

:)

Answer (score 0):

There's a feature to specify the table properties with a template on how the data can be read, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-dynamic-id-partitioning.html

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc (
  key_id STRING,
  value_text STRING,
  price INT
)
PARTITIONED BY (source_locale STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://path_to_my_data/abc_dataset/source_lang=en_US/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    "parquet.compress"="SNAPPY",
    "projection.enabled" = "true",
    "projection.device_id.type" = "injected",
    "storage.location.template" = "s3://path_to_my_data/abc_dataset/${source_lang}"
);
```